# call function with parameter in component

Tags: angular

I have zero knowledge about angular2 but trying to add feature to existing code.

This is function call in component:

```
<a (click)="somefunction()">TEST</a>
```

I'd like to call it with parameter. How to do it? Because passing it like this is not working: `(click)="somefunction(something='test')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign a variable when you call the function as the typing should be handled in your javascript. The below code assumes you are using ts and html that are in the same component.

I quickly put together a component to help give you some context.

HTML

```
        <tr *ngFor="let staff of allStaff">
            <td>{{staff.name}}</td>
            <td>{{staff.position}}</td>
            <td>{{staff.created_at}}</td>
            <td><button (click)="here(staff)"><span>View</span></button>
        </tr>
```

TS

```
import { Component, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { StaffService } from '../staff.service';

import { Staff } from '../staff';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './view-all.component.html'
})

export class ViewAllComponent {
  allStaff: Staff[];

  constructor(
    private staffService: StaffService,
  ) {
    this.getAllStaff();
  };

  getAllStaff(): void {
    this.staffService.getAllStaff().then(res => this.allStaff = res);
  };

  here(staff: Staff): void {
    console.log(staff);
  }
}
```